# How can I insert elements into a multimap?

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, containers, multimap

I want to set up a `multimap` in C++ as follows:

```
multimap<pair<string, string>, vector<double> > mmList;
```

But how can I insert data into it? I tried the following code, but it doesn't compile:

```
mmList.insert(pair<string, string>, vector<double>("a", "b", test));
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can construct pairs using `std::make_pair(a, b)`. Generally you can insert pairs into maps/multimaps. In your case you have to construct a pair consisting of the string pair and the vector:

```
    std::multimap<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::vector<double> > mmList;

    std::vector<double> vec;
    mmList.insert(std::make_pair(std::make_pair("a","b"), vec));
```

Answer (score 8):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can use [`std::multimap::emplace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace) to get rid of one `std::make_pair()` compared to [harpun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14538357/2675154):

```
std::multimap<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, std::vector<double>> mmList;
std::vector<double> test = { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 };
mmList.emplace(std::make_pair("a", "b"), test);
```

The code above is no only shorter, but also more efficient, because it reduces the number of unnecessary calls of [`std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) constructors.
To further increase efficiency, you can use the `piecewise_construct` constructor of `std::pair`, which was introduced specifically for your use case:

```
mmList.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
    std::forward_as_tuple("a", "b"),
    std::forward_as_tuple(test));
```

This code is no longer shorter, but has the effect that no unnecessary constructors are called. The objects are created directly in the `std::multimap` from the given arguments.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/qUU3Jj)

Answer (score 2):

Here is example:

```
std::multimap<std::string,std::string> Uri_SessionId_Map;
std::string uri = "http";
std::string sessId = "1001";
std::pair<std::string,std::string> myPair(uri,sessId);
Uri_SessionId_Map.insert(myPair);
```

Just broke up few lines for more readability. You can understand how to make pair. pair must have same templatize form as multimap.